# Inserting new row in table from Ajax dynamically

Tags: html, ajax, json

I am getting json string from the web service and want display that in html page. I have used ajax for dynamically displaying the row in the table. But the problem is all record are present in the single row.

Code:

```
 function showall(){

        var user = document.getElementById("user_name").value;
        alert(user);
         var row = $("<tr>");
         var nextrow = $("</tr>");

           $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "webresources/hello/showrequests",
           data : user,
           success : function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $.each(data, function(index, store){
                   $.each(store, function(key,value){
                       row.append($("<td>").html(value));
                      });
               $('#requests').append(row);      
               $('#requests').append(nextrow);
               });           

            },
           error: function(e){
                alert("error"+e+"has occured");
            }
        });

    }
```

and html body

```
<body onload="showall();">
        <h1><%=user%></h1>
        <input type="hidden" value="<%=user%>" id="user_name">
        <table border="1" id="requests" style="border-collapse: collapse">
            <tr>
                <th>RequestId</th>
                <th>Request</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Subcategory</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
```

output comes like

```
col11 | col12 | col13 | col21 | col22 | col23|
```

And i am expecting like

```
col11 | col12 | col13 | 
col21 | col22 | col23|
```

The JSONArray which I am sending from web service is like

```
[{"requestid":1,"request":"Increase RAM from 4GB to 8GB","category":"Hardware","subcategory":"To increase the RAM","department":"System","status":"Pending for approval"},{"requestid":2,"request":"Increase RAM from 2GB to 4GB\n","category":"Hardware","subcategory":"To increase the RAM","department":"System","status":"Pending for approval"},{"requestid":3,"request":"Increase RAM from 1 GB to 4 GB","category":"Hardware","subcategory":"To increase the RAM","department":"System","status":"Pending for approval"}]
```

What I need to do in ajax more?
Thank you

Comment: What is the html output?

Comment: as I have posted in question, col11-col23 comes in single row it should be in separate row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem looks to me to be that row is fetched outside of your loop. So essentially you are adding to that row, appending it, and then re-using that same object (with previous appends) to complete your next round of data appending. You need to create your new row object each time (inside your loop).

Update:
See this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/EKAyiLa/5/edit?html,js,output)

```
function showall(){

    var user = document.getElementById("user_name").value;
       $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "webresources/hello/showrequests",
       data : user,
       success : function(data){
            $.each(resp, function(index, store){
              var tr = $('<tr></tr>');

              $.each(store, function(key,value){
                tr.append($('<td></td>').html(value));
              });

              $('#requests').append(tr);
            });
        },
       error: function(e){
            alert("error"+e+"has occured");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question and added the jsonarray which it is parsing

Comment: I have updated my answer to include an example and a jsbin example as well.

Answer (score 0):

can you move this line

```
 $('#requests').append(row);
```

before

```
 $.each(store, function(key,value){
```

Comment: did that, but no change

Comment: success : function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function(index, store){
         $('#requests').append(row);       
         $.each(store, function(key,value){
                $('#requests').append($("<td>").html(value));
              }); 
       $('#requests').append(nextrow);
       });

Answer (score 0):

```
 success : function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function(index, store){
         $('#requests').append(row);       
         $.each(store, function(key,value){
                $('#requests').append($("<td>").html(value));
              }); 
       $('#requests').append(nextrow);
       });
```

Comment: Tried with this but no change

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing it like this so elements wont be unnecessary parsed. First create a string with html than add it to the dom.

```
var html = '';
$.each(data, function(index, store){
    html += '<tr>';
    $.each(store, function(key,value){
        html += '<td>'+value+'</td>';
    });
    html+= '</tr>';
}); 
$('#requests').append(html);
```